# How to make pandas.Dataframe.from_items show all data in a column.

Tags: python, pandas

Currently running into the issue of when I run this code:

`df = pandas.DataFrame.from_items(solutionDict.items(),orient='index', columns=['Room','Teacher','Time','Students'])`

It is giving me this output.

```
Room  Teacher  Time                                           Students
1      1        5     1  [14, 21, 31, 43, 65, 71, 2, 3, 19, 49, 58, 64,...
2      8        9     4            [4, 35, 45, 94, 18, 86, 99, 36, 56, 80]
3      8        3     1  [54, 60, 17, 33, 56, 67, 82, 95, 25, 30, 97, 1...
4      4        7     7  [62, 88, 92, 13, 37, 46, 59, 66, 71, 86, 89, 1...
5      4        8     5  [18, 33, 46, 63, 84, 100, 20, 23, 29, 53, 5, 7...
```

I am trying to figure out how to remove the ... from the end of the list 1 so that it would look more like list 2. I have tried using the

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

But I think that is the wrong option I am changing. I havent used pandas before and I am just a little confused.

Comment: Have you tried pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)?

Comment: @Mokshyam  That resulted in some weird indentation and putting the student column below the other 4. Maybe thats what pandas does when it doesnt have more space but not sure.

Comment: Add this option and check: pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True). More options are here: [Pandas Options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)